# How to Disable Datepicker when the input box is readonly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

How to turn off datepicker when input box is in readonly?
Here is my textbox

```html
<input type="text" name="letter_date" value="12/05/2019"  id="letter_date" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Nota" data-toggle="datepicker" readonly="readonly" />
```

and I have tried using this javascript code but when I select the textbox it is still showing datepicker.

```js
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(i) {
      if ($(this).prop('readonly')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
        }
    },
    format : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoHide : true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable the `datepicker` with `datepicker("option", "disabled", true);`.

```js
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(i) {
        if ($(this).prop('readonly')) {
          console.log('readonly is true');
          $(this).datepicker("option", "disabled", true);
          return;
        }
    },
    format : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoHide : true,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="letter_date" value="12/05/2019"  
    id="letter_date" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Nota" 
    data-toggle="datepicker" readonly="readonly"/>
```

--Edit--

For `multiple` inputs

```js
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(i) {
        if ($(this).prop('readonly')) {
          $(this).datepicker("option", "disabled", true);
          return;
        } 
    },
    format : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoHide : true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input type="text" name="letter_date" value="12/05/2019"  
    id="letter_date" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Nota" 
    data-toggle="datepicker" readonly/>

<input type="text" name="letter_date" value="12/05/2019"  
id="letter_date1" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Nota" 
data-toggle="datepicker"/>

<input type="text" name="letter_date" value="12/05/2019"  
id="letter_date2" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Masukkan Tanggal Nota" 
data-toggle="datepicker" readonly/>
```

Comment: This is looks works but somehow it doesn't. Is it possible that not work because I have serveral textbox that use ```data-toggle="datepicker"``` parameter?

Comment: @AtokG - It will work for multiple `inputs` too. See Edit. Just don't set same `id's` to `inputs` as they are `unique`.

Comment: still not work, is it because I use ```readonly="readonly"``` instead of just ```readonly``` ?

Comment: what is `readonly="readonly"?` `readonly` is a `boolean` attribute - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#readonly. If this attribute is present, it is considered true. So no need to add the value to attribute `readonly`.

Comment: I use Form helper from Codeigniter, it is set by default as ```readonly="readonly"``` and cannot be only ```readonly```

Comment: @AtokG - Ohh. It works with `readonly="readonly"` too. See first example in code snippet. I have updated. Did you get any error? You can create the fiddle to recreate the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Code :

```
$('[data-toggle="datepicker"]').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(i) {
      if ($(this).prop('readonly')) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return false;
        }
    },
    format : 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoHide : true,
    disabled: true
});
```